# ReactQuery await .mutate

Tags: react-query

Ok, I'n new to reactQuery and cant wrap my head around this.

useUpdateUserSettings is a import from a custom hook.

I have a page that calls this function:

```
  const updateUserSettingsMutation = useUpdateUserSettings();

  updateUserSettingsMutation.mutate({
    userName: user.preferred_username,
    settings: {
      ...settings,
      treatmentCountryGuid: country?.id || "",
      legalDepartmentGuid: division?.legalDepartmentGuid || "",
      defaultLanguage: selectedLanguage || "",
      treatmentCountryCode: country?.code || "",
      shopCode: division?.shopName?.substring(0, 2) || "",
    },
  });
```

Here is the function:

```
export function useUpdateUserSettings() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation(
    async (vars: { userName: string; settings: IUserSettingsForUpdate }) =>
    await putAccountSettings(vars.userName, vars.settings),
    {
      onMutate: async () => {
        queryClient.cancelQueries(useUserSettings.queryKey);
      },
      onSettled: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries(useUserSettings.queryKey),
    },
  );
}
```

On the page that calls updateUserSettingsMutation I need to await it to finish before the code continues.

**UPDATE:**
It can be done like this:

```
updateUserSettingsMutation.mutate({
  userName: user.preferred_username,
  settings: {
    ...settings,
    treatmentCountryGuid: country?.id || "",
    legalDepartmentGuid: division?.legalDepartmentGuid || "",
    defaultLanguage: selectedLanguage || "",
    treatmentCountryCode: country?.code || "",
    shopCode: division?.shopName?.substring(0, 2) || "",
  },
}, { onSuccess: () => { Some code }})
```

Comment: Where are you calling `useUpdateUserSettings`, and where exactly do you call `updateUserSettingsMutation.mutate`? We need some context.

Comment: What is `putAccountSettings`? Does it even return a promise that you can usefully `await`?

Comment: Updated post. But looks like i can use .mutateAsync and then with a .then() at the end

Comment: Are you saying that `updateUserSettingsMutation.mutate(…)` is called whenever you render the React component? That is a very bad idea.

Comment: No, it inside a function that is run on a click of a button

Comment: Then please share that code. And yes, you should be able to just `await` it.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of calling updateUserSettingsMutation.mutate, you would use updateUserSettingsMutation.mutateAsync. This allows you to await the completion of the mutation.

```
const updateUserSettingsMutation = useUpdateUserSettings();

await updateUserSettingsMutation.mutateAsync({
  userName: user.preferred_username,
  settings: {
    // ... your settings object
  },
});
```

For more details: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/mutations#promises

Answer (score 0):

```
updateUserSettingsMutation.mutate({
  userName: user.preferred_username,
  settings: {
    ...settings,
    treatmentCountryGuid: country?.id || "",
    legalDepartmentGuid: division?.legalDepartmentGuid || "",
    defaultLanguage: selectedLanguage || "",
    treatmentCountryCode: country?.code || "",
    shopCode: division?.shopName?.substring(0, 2) || "",
  },
}, { onSuccess: () => { Some code }})
```

Comment: so you didn't have to async/await?..

Answer (score -1):

I think you need the syntax for this. An example:

```js
const { mutate: createUser } = useCreateUser();


createUser(user, {
  onSuccess(data, variables, context) {
     setSuccess(true);
  },
  onError(error, variables, context) {
     setError(error);
  },
});
```